# Is there any documentation for the Cassandra Erlang interface?

Tags: erlang, cassandra, thrift

I have looked everywhere, and to use Cassandra from Erlang you end up having to download (amongst others):

boost
thrift

: and then you have generate the erlang library by hand, and then copy lib files and beams files. Once you have the whole thing working there is absolutely zero documentation anywhere. If anyone could show me some user friendly documentation it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [ThriftExmples](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples) page on the Apache Cassandra wiki page is probably the best place to start. The current examples are using PHP, Python, Java, Perl and C#.

The examples, and the documentation, should hopefully help you with some Cassandra basics (e.g diff ColumnParent & ColumnPath)

The entire Cassandra API is documented [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API)

Feel free to add API examples using Erlang on the wiki page.

Comment: Yes, I've seen all the available documentation. The problem is that I'm not a developer, and all the documentation seems to be oriented towards people who have a lot of time to fully understand Thrift as well. I was hoping that they would at least put up some example code on the web for Erlang. Is there a commercial company behind it too, maybe it is a case that I should get a support contract with them to get the correct documentation, much like it is with the Oracle store.